# How to fix the header in Angular application

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 9 and i have 2 components: header and body.

In the `AppComponent`, I'm stuck to fix the position of the header (in red) in the top! The problem is the body (in blue) is over the header...

```css
app-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;  /* for demo purpose */
  background: red; /* for demo purpose */
  height: 50px;    /* for demo purpose */
}

.body {
  position: sticky;
  border: 4px solid blue; /* for demo purpose */
  height: 800px;          /* for demo purpose */
}
```

```html
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="body">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: Use display: grid and create 3 rows in root page.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are doing it is wrong you can use this

```
.html

<div class="app-header">
    <app-header></app-header>
</div>

.css

.app-header{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}
```

you can't give css to your compnent with it's name 
a;so you can do this solution in your app-header which means wraping them all in a div and giving the style to it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container and apply `display: flex` to your header. Let me show an example:

Styles:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

app-header {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
}

.main {
     flex: 1;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <app-header>
        Header
    </app-header>
    <div class="main">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```